Trying to write a C program to remove all comments from a C program
I am trying to make a program to remove all comments in a C program. I believe this is a common exercise in most C books.
The code is as follows:
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>

 #define ON 1
 #define OFF 0
    
    int main()
    {
        FILE* fs, * ft;
        int c = 1, c_prev = 1, slcomment = OFF, mlcomment = OFF, d_quotes = OFF;
    
        fs = fopen("source.c", "rb");
        ft = fopen("target.c", "wb");
    
        c_prev = fgetc(fs);
    
        while ((c = fgetc(fs)) != EOF)
        {
        if (c == '"' && d_quotes == OFF)
            d_quotes = ON;
    
        if (c == '"' && d_quotes == ON)
            d_quotes = OFF;
    
            if (c_prev == '/')
            {
                if (c == '/' && d_quotes == OFF)
                    slcomment = ON;
    
                else if (c == '*' && d_quotes == OFF)
                    mlcomment = ON;
    
                else
                    fputc(c_prev, ft);
            }
    
            if (c == '\n' && slcomment == ON)
                slcomment = OFF;
    
            if (c_prev == '*' && c == '/' && mlcomment == ON && d_quotes == OFF)
            {
                mlcomment = OFF;
                c = fgetc(fs);
            }
    
            if (c != '/' && mlcomment == OFF && slcomment == OFF && d_quotes == OFF)
                fputc(c, ft);
    
            c_prev = c;
        }
    
        fclose(fs);
        fclose(ft);
        printf("Program, after removal of comments, has been copied in target.c...\n");
    
        getch();
        return 0;
    }

The program seems to work fine except that it cant remove the first '/' when there is a single line comment.
I just cant seem to figure out what is going wrong. Please point out the mistake. Thank you all in advance.

It is not as easy as "/*" or "*/" can be a part of the string literal. char s[] = "/* it is not comment */";

Thanks for pointing out. I have tried to include that too in my code.

Also remeber that that the quote character can be included in the string literal char x[] = "hello \"world\"";

Also (...advanced...) you can split a // comment into more than one line with \<newline> ... but, please please PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS in real code

"I believe this is a common exercise in most C books." If you do it right, it might be way more complex than what is appropriate for a beginners C book.

If you're willing to forgo the requirement to implement this using C, I recommend using Antlr, the grammar for C, and the Trash toolkit to strip comments in a canned, turnkey manner.
Step 1 -- Clone the grammar repo
$ git clone https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4.git
Cloning into 'grammars-v4'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 50591, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1880/1880), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1267/1267), done.
remote: Total 50591 (delta 675), reused 1605 (delta 501), pack-reused 48711
Receiving objects: 100% (50591/50591), 47.49 MiB | 22.49 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (27096/27096), done.
Updating files: 100% (9413/9413), done.

Step 2 -- Generate a parser for C
$ cd grammars-v4/c
$ trgen -t CSharp
C:\msys64\home\Kenne\temp\grammars-v4\c
CSharp  C.g4 success 0.0547772
Rendering template file from CSharp/Other.csproj to ./Generated-CSharp/Other.csproj
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.build.ps1 to ./Generated-CSharp/st.build.ps1
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.build.sh to ./Generated-CSharp/st.build.sh
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.clean.ps1 to ./Generated-CSharp/st.clean.ps1
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.clean.sh to ./Generated-CSharp/st.clean.sh
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.Encodings.cs to ./Generated-CSharp/st.Encodings.cs
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.ErrorListener.cs to ./Generated-CSharp/st.ErrorListener.cs
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.makefile to ./Generated-CSharp/st.makefile
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.perf.sh to ./Generated-CSharp/st.perf.sh
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.ProfilingCommonTokenStream.cs to ./Generated-CSharp/st.ProfilingCommonTokenStream.cs
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.run.ps1 to ./Generated-CSharp/st.run.ps1
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.run.sh to ./Generated-CSharp/st.run.sh
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.test-cover.sh to ./Generated-CSharp/st.test-cover.sh
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.Test.cs to ./Generated-CSharp/st.Test.cs
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.test.ps1 to ./Generated-CSharp/st.test.ps1
Rendering template file from CSharp/st.test.sh to ./Generated-CSharp/st.test.sh
Rendering template file from CSharp/Test.csproj.st to ./Generated-CSharp/Test.csproj.st
Copying source file from C:/msys64/home/Kenne/temp/grammars-v4/c/desc.xml to ./Generated-CSharp/desc.xml
Copying source file from C:/msys64/home/Kenne/temp/grammars-v4/c/C.g4 to ./Generated-CSharp/C.g4
$ cd Generated-CSharp/
$ make
bash build.sh
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\msys64\home\Kenne\temp\grammars-v4\c\Generated-CSharp\Test.csproj (in 564 ms).
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Test -> C:\msys64\home\Kenne\temp\grammars-v4\c\Generated-CSharp\bin\Debug\net8.0\Test.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:08.09

Step 3 -- Run tools from command line to strip comments
$ cat input.c
// Includes for a bunch of stuff.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

/* Lot's of #defines.... */
#define ON 1
#define OFF 0

/*
 * the main program.
 */
int main()
{
        FILE* fs, * ft; // Bunches of files.
        int c = 1, c_prev = 1, slcomment = OFF, mlcomment = OFF, d_quotes = OFF;

        fs = fopen("source.c", "rb"); // open a bunch of files.
        ft = fopen("target.c", "wb");

        c_prev = fgetc(fs); // Read a char ------ bug

        // Read a char, until EOF.
        while ((c = fgetc(fs)) != EOF)
        {
                if (c == '"' && d_quotes == OFF)
                {
                        d_quotes = ON;
                        fputc (c, ft);
                        c = fgetc (fs);
                } // end if

                if (c == '"' && d_quotes == ON)
                {
                        d_quotes = OFF;
                        fputc (c, ft);
                        c = fgetc (fs);
                }

                if (c_prev == '/')
                {
                        if (c == '/' && d_quotes == OFF)
                                slcomment = ON;

                        if (c == '*' && d_quotes == OFF)
                                mlcomment = ON;

                        if (slcomment == OFF && mlcomment == OFF && d_quotes == OFF)
                                fputc(c_prev, ft);
                }

                if (c == '\n' && slcomment == ON)
                        slcomment = OFF;

                if (c_prev == '*' && c == '/' && mlcomment == ON && d_quotes == OFF)
                {
                        mlcomment = OFF;
                        c = fgetc(fs);
                }

                if (c != '/' && mlcomment == OFF && slcomment == OFF && d_quotes == OFF)
                        fputc (c, ft);

                if (d_quotes == ON)
                        fputc (c, ft);

                c_prev = c;
        } // end-while

        fclose(fs); // Close files.
        fclose(ft);
        printf("Program, after removal of comments, has been copied in target.c...\n");

        getch();
        return 0;
}
$ trparse input.c | trquery delete ' //(@BlockComment | @LineComment)' | trsponge -o xxx -c
CSharp 0 input.c success 0.0696287
Writing to xxx/input.c
$ diff input.c xxx/
1c1
< // Includes for a bunch of stuff.
---
>
6c6
< /* Lot's of #defines.... */
---
>
10,12c10
< /*
<  * the main program.
<  */
---
>
15c13
<       FILE* fs, * ft; // Bunches of files.
---
>       FILE* fs, * ft;
18c16
<       fs = fopen("source.c", "rb"); // open a bunch of files.
---
>       fs = fopen("source.c", "rb");
21c19
<       c_prev = fgetc(fs); // Read a char ------ bug
---
>       c_prev = fgetc(fs);
23c21
<       // Read a char, until EOF.
---
>
31c29
<               } // end if
---
>               }
68c66
<       } // end-while
---
>       }
70c68
<       fclose(fs); // Close files.
---
>       fclose(fs);

How does this work?
Antlr is a general parser generator for various programming language environments and OSes, and different grammars. The grammars-v4 repo contains over 350 grammars (NB, many are not completely up-to-date with current state of programming languages, and the grammars may have bugs).
Trash is a toolkit for Antlr parse tree manipulations, and works with the grammars in the grammars-v4 repo. Tools create parser applications from a grammar, parse input and output parse trees. Additional tools work with an XPath engine to find and manipulate nodes in the parse tree.
For this example, the parse tree contains nodes for BlockComment and LineComment. These are deleted using the trquery command, identified using the XPath expression //(@BlockComment | @LineComment) (attributes in the parse tree are prefaced with @). The modified parse tree is then outputted to file using trsponge.

Thank you so much, thats an elaborate reply. I will study it in detail. :)

From looking on your code, the problem is not on the first '/', but on the second '/'. And it is caused by this code:
if (c_prev == '/')
{
    if (c == '/')
        slcomment = ON;
    else if (c == '*')
        mlcomment = ON;
    else
        fputc(c_prev, ft);
}

c_prev is '/' since it's the second character. c can be anything here, since it's from the commented line. Then it will reach the else statement, which will insert the '/' character.
You should call this block of code only when slcomment and mlcomment are OFF.

I managed to fix a few bugs and following program seems to be working
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>

 #define ON 1
 #define OFF 0
    
    int main()
    {
        FILE* fs, * ft;
        int c = 1, c_prev = 1, slcomment = OFF, mlcomment = OFF, d_quotes = OFF;
    
        fs = fopen("source.c", "rb");
        ft = fopen("target.c", "wb");
    
        c_prev = fgetc(fs);
    
        while ((c = fgetc(fs)) != EOF)
        {
        if (c == '"' && d_quotes == OFF)
            {
        d_quotes = ON;
        fputc (c, ft);
        c = fgetc (fs);
        }
    
        if (c == '"' && d_quotes == ON)
            {
        d_quotes = OFF;
        fputc (c, ft);
        c = fgetc (fs);
        }
    
            if (c_prev == '/')
            {
                if (c == '/' && d_quotes == OFF)
                    slcomment = ON;
    
                if (c == '*' && d_quotes == OFF)
                    mlcomment = ON;
    
                if (slcomment == OFF && mlcomment == OFF && d_quotes == OFF)
                    fputc(c_prev, ft);
            }
    
            if (c == '\n' && slcomment == ON)
                slcomment = OFF;
    
            if (c_prev == '*' && c == '/' && mlcomment == ON && d_quotes == OFF)
            {
                mlcomment = OFF;
                c = fgetc(fs);
            }
    
            if (c != '/' && mlcomment == OFF && slcomment == OFF && d_quotes == OFF)
                fputc (c, ft);
    
        if (d_quotes == ON)
        fputc (c, ft);
    
            c_prev = c;
        }
    
        fclose(fs);
        fclose(ft);
        printf("Program, after removal of comments, has been copied in target.c...\n");
    
        getch();
        return 0;
    }

Please do point out mistakes if any. Thanks a lot.

You should consider using a state machine, instead of using the conditions. There are a lot of advantages by using a state machine. You can make a more reliable implementation, make the algorithm more modularized, easier to read and debug. This does not apply just to your problem, but to any logic that involves clear and definite states.

Well, the task you plan is a difficult task, as not only you have to check for /* and */ in your code, but probably more than just those.
You need to check all C tokens that can embedd a comment starting sequence, because in that case the comment will not start a comment (e.g. a string literal needs to be properly parsed and identified, to avoid a /* sequence be detected incorrectly inside a quoted string) This means also that you have to consider that a double quoted can be quoted inside a string literal to avoid terminating the string prematurely.
For all such tokens, the start of a comment should not be interpreted, and the read characters should be copied to the output stream.
Below there's a lex(1) specification for a comment filter that eliminates C comments on input.  The finite automaton it creates will scan the input from stdin and will output to stdout, the code is simple and you will be able to analize the produced C code.
comment.l
str             ([^\\\n]|\\.)*

%%

"/*"([^\*]|\*[^/])*"*/"         ;
"//".*$                         ;
\"{str}\"                       ECHO;
\'{str}\'                       ECHO;
.                               ECHO;

A gross estimate of the number of states the DFA will have will probably put it between 20 and 100 states.
To compile this just:
$ lex -t comment.l > comment.c
$ cc -c comment.c -o comment.o
$ cc -o comment comment.o -lfl

The program will read from stdin, and will output to stdout.
Sorry but creating a full automaton for this problem is a bit out of scope and will require a lot of time to develop manually and test.  I have not contempled in thi example string literals can hold characters specified a unicode char literals (\uxxxx) or octal/hex escapes,  which probably should have been considered.
Finally, I recommend you to use flex(1)/lex(1) for this purpose, as the compilation of regular set of tokens into a DFA is a complex task, error prone and easily implemented with these tools.
